# Store a value to reference in same firebase database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, esp8266

I am storing ESP8266 data in a Firebase Real time database.
I also want to store a calibration value ( example 123123999999) in the database and if/when the ESP8266 turns on from a power outage, it would read the database for the calibration value.  In SQL database I would set the key to a specific key like 01011900 but with Firebase's JSON structure, I am not sure how to preset the key and retrieve this value.

When storing the data in the database I am using a json.set for each data point.